# how to echo ascii encrypted text in php

Tags: php, javascript, character-encoding, escaping, ascii

I am trying to echo an ascii crypted text like this:

```
$x = encrypt("hello there");
 echo $x;
```

the encrypt function returns

```
&#104&#101&#108&#108&#111&#32&#116&#104&#101&#114&#101
```

but on the screen it is printed as "hello there".

how can i print the original ascii value ?

Comment: removed the encryption tag in favor of [character-encoding] and [escaping], since the encryption tag is limited to encryption in the cryptographic sense of the word (the PHP function is not that well named in my opinion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `htmlentities()` around encrypt to escape the &.

```
$x = htmlentities(encrypt("hello there"));
 echo $x;
```

Comment: this is perfect..! need to wait another 8 mins to accept this as result!

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = encrypt("hello there");
echo htmlentities($x);
```